# AFM of Smooth Amorphous Carbon

Tags: physical-chemistry, thin-films

I have been having trouble getting decent resolution images and clear data of smooth amorphous carbon thin films prepared by RF bias assisted vacuum deposition. I was using a DLC tip in tapping mode and was able to get some data but is not exactly repeatable, with many more films to analyse acquiring results has been difficult and time consuming. With rms values ~0.125 and variation of hybridisation from CDE contour plots this may be an awkward task with the old machine we have and the point to point variation of conductivity.

Are there are suggestions for tips, scan parameters, scan modes etc. I am no expert with AFM by any stretch so any advice would be helpful

Much appreciated!